# Is it possible to run a class outside of the workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run a class that is outside of the workspace that I work in.

I am working on Eclipse.

Is it possible to invoke a class that is outside of the workspace?

Comment: Yes make a jar file and add it to your class path as an external jar reference.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Eclipse knows little about files not present in the project tree of any project. However you can use "Configure Build Path", tab "Libraries", "Add External Class Folder" and specify the path to the folder where your class files exist. After that this folder will become a part of project classpath and you can specify any class from that folder as the main class in your Launch configuration.